# My son will be moving from Indianapolis to Seattle at the end of January driving a small uhaul. what is the safest route through mountains?

Tags: winter, seattle

I am looking for safest route through the mountains with winter weather.

Comment: (1) don't drive in winter weather. (2) be prepared to stay someplace. (3) reroute as needed. The interstates will be fine a day or two after a big storm (generally). Last spring I drove to Oregon from the southwest. The fastest route was through Salt Lake City and Boise. Big storm coming in, so I went the Vegas and north. Bonus was seeing some beautiful country I hadn't seen before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have two choices, I-90 and I-80 to I-84.  I-90 is more direct, but only by a few hours.

Both routes are as safe as any interstate highway except during snow storms and shortly thereafter.  I would plan to take I-90 unless there were a snowstorm that somehow affected I-90 without affecting I-80 or I-84.  If there were a snowstorm affecting both, it would probably be best just to wait it out.

In other words, use the weather forecast to decide which route to take.

Comment: I just googled it and the I-80/I-84 route wasn't mentioned.  Instead there was an I-74/I-80/Rt 380/I-29 meeting I-90 at Sioux Falls.  Or I-94/I-90 via Fargo.  The latter goes through Chicago, which may be best to be avoided.  Both routes clock in a 33 hrs, and the I-80/I-84 route clocks in a 34 hours.

Comment: @PeterM I was only thinking of options to get through the mountains.  If you're taking I-90, there are a few ways to get to Billings; I would avoid Chicago.

Comment: The National Weather Service's [Probabilistic Precipitation Forecast](https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/pwpf/wwd_accum_probs.php) is extremely useful for figuring out where bad driving weather will be in the next 72 hours.  It does take a bit of work to interpret, though.

Comment: Going I-80 out to Salt Lake City, then north, potentially ducking over to Portland to avoid the Washington Cascades to go up I-5. Adds about an hour or so over the other routes. So just watch the forecast and pick. Lots of ways to bounce back and forth as well.

Comment: Instead of the I-80 start on the I-70 to Denver even?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  We are considering all of these options for routes and certainly will watch the weather very closely.  Any additional feedback on the specific mountain routes is appreciated.   Is there any information on rest stops, gas stations, etc anywhere that could help in the trip planning or do we have to look state by state?  Thanks again!